# Bring remote branch into Git and then add back my changes without creating new branch

Tags: git

I need to merge code from a remote branch into my working branch. The merge is so complicated I feel more comfortable bringing in the remote branch and then adding back my code. Is there a way to "stash" my changes so that I can add them back without having to create another new branch just to merge the changes?

Comment: Could you explain the behavior you expect in more detail? Do you want to merge the changes from the remote, but keep your changes where there are conflicts? Or do you want to keep the same exact working directory?

Comment: The changes in the remote are so extensive that going file by file trying to resolve the changes would be challenging. I would rather bring down the latest from all the other developers and add my code back in manually inside visual studio as opposed to using a merge editor. To that end I was wondering if there was a way to keep my current code available without copying it all to a separate directory. In the past I have created s separate branch just for the merge itself and copied my code over to a separate directory and then pulled what I needed back into the merge branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're after is:

```
$ git fetch
$ git merge --strategy recursive -Xours origin/<branch-name>
```

This will merge the changes from the remote branch `origin/<branch-name>` into the current branch and, if there are any conflicts, your changes will "win".

Another thing you can do is perform a regular Merge and then resolve the conflicts by picking your version for each conflicting file:

```
$ git checkout --ours -- path/to/file
```

AFAIK, there isn't a straightforward way to "stash" changes that have been already committed. Even if there was, you would still have to somehow fix the conflicts when applying the stash back to the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can use the

```
 git stash
```

command to do exactly that. The documentation is here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: I want to save my changes and then bring the working directory to be the same as a different remote branch (the one I want to merge into). This is a different branch than I started with. So I can't just change the `HEAD` to revert to a previous commit.

Comment: As long as you haven't committed your changes, you should be able to 'git stash', merge the remote branch into your working directory, and then 'git stash pop' to reapply your changes.